# I got stuck with firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I recently learned about developing applications, and I have difficulty adding Firestore user accounts to the task application, I use flutter and pluginshttps://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chips_input.

> 1. User is not appear on app, how i adding user to my task?
> 2. How i assign task to my user and can read the task created?

```
static const userResults = <User>[];
ChipsInput(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Select Team",
  ),
  maxChips: 3,
  findSuggestions: (String query) {
    if (query.length != 0) {
      var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
      return userResults.where((user) {
        return 
          user.displayName
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(query.toLowerCase()) 
          || user.email
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(query.toLowerCase());
      }).toList(growable: false)
        ..sort((a, b) => a.displayName
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(lowercaseQuery)
            .compareTo(b.displayName
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(lowercaseQuery)
            )
        );
    } else {
      return userResults;
    }
  },
  onChanged: (data) {
    print(data);
  },
  chipBuilder: (context, state, _) {
    return InputChip(
      key: ObjectKey(widget.user),
      label: Text(widget.user.fullName),
      avatar: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.user.photoUrl),
      ),
      onDeleted: () => state.deleteChip(widget.user),
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    );
  },
  suggestionBuilder: (context, state, _) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ObjectKey(widget.user),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.user.photoUrl),
      ),
      title: Text(widget.user.fullName),
      subtitle: Text(widget.user.email),
      onTap: () => state.selectSuggestion(widget.user),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: There is no actual question in your post. and it should be more concise. Please check the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask